# how to capture grater than symbol parameter to build date field comparison in where clause for SSRS parameter report

Tags: reporting-services

new to SSRS report design.  Although, I've used CASE statement before but not sure how to utilize in a condition where SSRS report needs to two parameters ( parameter symbol (>,<,=,%) and parameter date ) pull data from a dataset.

I'm wondering if CASE statement can be used to achieve this need?
Or any other suggestion that would work for this condition, will be greatly appreciated.

PS:  I've not come across such example so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to parameterise the actual operator so the user can for example, choose < 1000 or > 50 etc...

If that's correct then you can do this as follows.

Assume we have two parameters

`pOperator` which has values of ">", "<" and "=" (note for the `=` option you will need to specify this as an expression `="="` or SSRS will think you have a blank expression.

`pMyValue` which will allow the users to type a number in

What you need to do is change the dataset query to be an expression, so something like this.

```
="SELECT Employee, Salary FROM myTable
     WHERE Salary " & Parameters!pOperator.Value & " " & Parameters!pMyValue.Value
```

If you had used `>` and `30000` as your parameter values then this would return

```
SELECT Employee, Salary FROM myTable
     WHERE Salary > 1000
```

You could also have a single parameter where the user can type the whole `">=15000"` and then just replace the two parameters above with a single one.

Comment: Appreciate you response and your assumption is correct.  but, when apply this "expression" , my dataset is not pulling any fields.  i'm not sure why?

Comment: add a textbox to your report and set the expression to the same as your dataset expression so you can see the query that is being executed, it might just be you need to wrap quotes round some values of something

Comment: Alan, thank you also for the 2nd suggestion "add a textbox "  -- that helps & works .. now I see what is being executed.  Thank you!